# Long space in content of UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I used an UIWebview to place some html contents parsed from JSON. I notice there's some long white space at the end of the line in! the text but I don't know why. Do you know how to get rid of them? Thanks.
[the problem looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wAne.png)

Comment: I can't see any "long white space at the end of the line". Can you be more specific? Can you also tell us which line you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstood. For eg, You see, at the middle of the text, at "...correct up to date...", it leaves a long space, so the next word "information" must break to a new line.

Comment: LOL, you mean not all the lines have the same width? as you are using a webview, I think the only way is to use CSS to align the text. body {text-align:justify}

Comment: This is because it doesn't fit in the line. To wrap these kind of words you have to edit the html resp. the css. For more information look [here](http://mozilla.org/en/css/word-wrap).